# Successive zeroing of columns of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `a` of ones and zeroes (it might be rather big)

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

in which the "upper" rows are more "important" in the sense that if there is 1 in any column of the i-th row, then all ones in that columns in the *following* rows must be zeroed.

So, the desired output should be:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

In other words, there should only be single 1 per column.

I'm looking for a more *numpy* way to do this (i.e. minimising or, better, avoiding the loops).

Comment: To clarify , do you mean the ```first one``` in each column should be made 1 and all else should be 0

Comment: Yes, the first (from "above") 1 in the given column must be kept while all the following zeroed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array:

```
     [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Transpose it with numpy:

`a = np.transpose(your_array)`

Now it looks like this:

```
  [[1, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Zero all the non-zero (and "not upper") elements row wise:

```
 res = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype="int64")
 idx =  np.arange(res.shape[0])
 args = a.astype(bool).argmax(1)
 res[idx, args] = a[idx, args]
```

The output of `res` is this:

```
 #### Output
  [[1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Re-transpose your array:

`a = np.transpose(res)`

```
  [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

EDIT: Thanks to @The.B for the tip

Comment: you have floats in your final array. `dtype="int64"` should come in handy.

Comment: Instead of using `np.transpose`, we can also chose to use `a.T` and `res.T` instead.

Comment: That works, thanks! Actually, you don't need `np.transpose` at all: `rows = a.argmax(axis=0)`, `cols = np.arange(a.shape[1])`. I.e. just flip axes.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to do a forward fill followed by the cumulative sum and then replace all values which are *not* 1 with 0:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

ff = np.maximum.accumulate(a, axis=0)
cs = np.cumsum(ff, axis=0)
cs[cs > 1] = 0
```

Output in `cs`:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**EDIT**

This will do the same thing and should be slightly more efficient:

```
ff = np.maximum.accumulate(a, axis=0)
ff ^ np.pad(ff, ((1,0), (0,0)))[:-1]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And if you want to do the operations in-place to avoid temporary memory allocation:

```
out = np.zeros((a.shape[0]+1, a.shape[1]), dtype=a.dtype)
np.maximum.accumulate(a, axis=0, out=out[1:])
out[:-1] ^ out[1:]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through each column of array and check if it is the first one -

If Not: Make it 0

```
for col in a.T:
  f=0
  for x in col:
    if(x==1 and f==0):
      f=1
    else:
      x=0
```